# JQuery Mobile slider not reacting to slidestop event

Tags: jquery-mobile, uislider

I am trying to get a slider to work using JQuery Mobile. Specifically, I would like the slider to react to the slidestop event.

I've made a JSFiddle here: [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/ubWL2/8/)

The thing that doesn't work is:

```
$('#ActualSlider').on('slidestop',function(){
     alert('slidestop');
});
```

There is something wrong, but I can't find the problem. Please help me out.

Comment: in fiddle, you need to wrap code in head to activate `pagecreate` event. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/X996s/

Comment: Thanks! That's the way. Actually thought JSFiddle would help solve my problem, but it created a new one...

Comment: The new one was the one you solved. Thanks again!